# C# HttpClient unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I have relatively big application that relies on http requests to several web pages. Nothing special, using HttpClient, setting headers and so on. Some users reported that their connections (either localhost or using proxy) were timing out.

So I ask them to land me the proxies so I can try. And they were right, the http requests were timing out. As I didn't understand why, I took the http requests related code to brand new Visual Studio project to debug it. And to my surprise, all was good in the new application. I can replicate this forever, works in new one, doesn't work in my main app.

Is anyone able to give me at least a hint why this is happening? Both are compiled with 4.6.1 (the main app is WPF application). I am literally lost. Any help will be much appreciated. I am not posting the code here as the issue is obviously not in there.

**UPDATE**
So updating to latest System.Net fixed the issue ...

Comment: Are you creating a new `HttpClient` object for every request? [This](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) might be helpful. Hard to know without seeing any of your code.

Comment: What is the version of HttpClient Dll?

Comment: no i am not, each task (separate thread) has it's own HttpClient object. Even if I edit the main app to run the http request at the beginning (in Main), still timing out.

Comment: @itsme86 Be careful with load balancing there

Comment: System.Net 4.0.0.0

Comment: As the other poster commented, load balancer can be one place to look into. Is the problem with only "some" clients or everyone? What is the difference? Hard to say anything before looking at the code.